# Android Deep Linking (Intents) Support in .NET MAUI

Tags: android, .net, maui

I am currently trying to add deep linking support (via Intents) to an Android application written using .NET MAUI.

I have added an **activity** XML element under the **application** element in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true">
      <activity android:name="TestApp.MainActivity" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="test"
                android:pathPrefix="/group" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

I have also added an **IntentFilter** to the MainActivity.cs under Platforms\Android (see below):

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[]
    {
        Intent.ActionView,
        Intent.CategoryDefault,
        Intent.CategoryBrowsable
    },
    DataScheme = "https", DataHost = "test", DataPathPrefix = "/group"
    )
]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
```

Just not sure what to do at this point to react (where to put event handler, etc.) to the intent.

If anyone has any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Was it enough to add this intent filter? Then by browsing https: //test/group the app will open?

Comment: @ScottexBoy once I registered the intent (i.e., the code shown above in my question), I deployed the application to my physically attached Android device and then when I attempted to open https://test/group from an email I sent myself on the phone, it gave me the option to open the URL using the Android App I built (or to open using Google Chrome).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can handle the `intent` by overriding `OnNewIntent` method .

Fetch the information from `intent.DataString` and do what you want.

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //test
        OnNewIntent(Intent);
    }

    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);

        var data = intent.DataString;

        if (intent.Action != Intent.ActionView) return;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data)) return;

        if (data.Contains("/group"))
        {
            //do what you want 
        }
    }
```