# How to handle Intents in a .net MAUI Blazor App

Tags: android-intent, maui, maui-blazor

I'm trying to handle Intents in a .net maui blazor app, I've registered the intents and got everything setup but when I click to 'open with the app' it just opens the root page of the app, seemingly ignoring my routing logic.

I've implemented the OnNewIntent action as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72696842/1662619

```
    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);

        var data = intent.DataString;

        if (intent.Action != Intent.ActionView) return;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data)) return;

        var path = data.Replace(@"https://mydomain.app", "");
        
        //Store the request path to be used in main.razor
        NavigationService.SetPage(path);

        StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
    }
```

But I can't ever get it to hit a breakpoint there (I guess cause it opens the app in a new instance).

Then in my Main.razor:

```
@code
{
    [Inject]
    public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        var intentPath = PreferencesHandler.GetIntentPath();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(intentPath))
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo(intentPath);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried added logging but the OnNewIntent logic seems to never get hit. Why not?

Comment: You said that you can't ever get it to hit a breakpoint. It means that OnNewIntent is not called. You can check the doc about [OnNewIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)): This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in their package, or if a client used the `Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag when calling `startActivity(Intent)`...

Comment: Thanks Jianwei, I got it to hit the breakpoint by `LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop` to the activity attribute. But how do I then handle the routing in a blazor app? The docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/app-actions?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android#responding-to-actions) only work for xaml app

Comment: You can refer to this blog about [Routing in Blazor Apps](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/routing-in-blazor-apps/) by official.

Comment: Yea I'm using the `@page` directives and normally navigate with `NavigationManager.NavigateTo(intentPath);` as in the code example but I can't call the NavManager from within the `OnNewIntent` action. Hence the attempt to pass the intent data string through to the Main.razor. It seems the issue won't be officially fixed until .net 8: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3788

Comment: You can follow up this issue to see if there is any new information.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you can get the intent in the OnCreate method too like so:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Intent intent = this.Intent;           
    var action = intent.Action;
    var strLink = intent.DataString;
    if (Intent.ActionView == action && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strLink))
    {               
         //handle intent routing
    }
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```