# Deep linking doesn't fire SendOnAppLinkRequestReceived when app closed on Android in dotnet maui

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

I am trying to implement Deep linking in .NET MAUI for iOS and Android. iOS works for me but Android only works partially.

I have everything setup, so the entries in my website is added and the app gets fired as well.

The issue I am facing is to Invoke SendOnAppLinkRequestReceived from OnCreate, when the app is created/opened.

this is my MainActivity code for Android.

```cs
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    AutoVerify = true, DataScheme = "test-app123")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    AutoVerify = true, DataScheme = "https", DataHost = "test.app123.app")]
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true,
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density,
    // Prevents MainActivitiy from being re-created on launching an intent (also makes it to where `OnNewIntent` will be called directly, if the app has already been loaded)
    LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask
)]
//[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        
        OnNewIntent(Intent);

    }

    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
      
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        
        string action = intent.Action;
        string strLink = intent.DataString;
       
        if (Intent.ActionView != action || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strLink))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Empty");
            return;
        }
        

        var link = new Uri(strLink);
        Console.WriteLine("Link " + link);
        App.Current.SendOnAppLinkRequestReceived(link);
    }

}
```

My app works as expected if the app is running in background and then try opening it using the link. the OnNewIntent gets called then the SendOnAppLinkRequestReceived.

But when the app is closed it doesn't call the SendOnAppLinkRequestReceived and instead gives me a error.

```
 android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Arg_TargetInvocationException
                                                                                                     ---> System.InvalidOperationException: MauiContext should have been set on parent.
```

This occurs when I call OnNewIntent in my OnCreate. But if I don't how can I invoke the SendOnAppLinkRequestReceived

Someone did suggest the same solution here [Android Deep Linking (Intents) Support in .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72686426/android-deep-linking-intents-support-in-net-maui) which is accepted but just doesnt work for me.

My App.Xaml.cs looks something like this:

```cs
public App()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        

        MainPage = new AppShell();
#if IOS
        (Application.Current as IApplicationController)?.SetAppIndexingProvider(new Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.iOS.IOSAppIndexingProvider());
#endif
#if ANDROID
        (Application.Current as IApplicationController)?.SetAppIndexingProvider(new 
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.Android.AndroidAppIndexProvider(Android.App.Application.Context));
#endif
       
#if IOS || ANDROID

        try
        {
            var entry = new AppLinkEntry
            {
                Title = "Find Shop",
                Description = "Find Shop Deep Link",
                
                
                AppLinkUri = new Uri("https://test.app123.app/", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                IsLinkActive = true
            };
            Application.Current.AppLinks.RegisterLink(entry);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Crash");
        }
#endif

    }
    
    // Package: a model class with a property packageUri (type Uri)
    protected async override void OnAppLinkRequestReceived(Uri uri)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(uri.ToString());
        Package package = new Package() { packageUri = uri };

        var navigationParameter = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "MyPackage", package } };
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(NewPage1)}", navigationParameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line of OnNewIntent causes the exception? Set breakpoint at start and step through it.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve in the App.Current.SendOnAppLinkRequestReceived(link) in App.Xaml.cs I try to navigate to a new page and display the uri. that is causing the crash. I can't use a debugger because the app run by itself works fine but with app link it crashes. For applink to work, I need to create a signed apk, so no debugger/breakpoint.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve https://stackoverflow.com/a/76667051/22207053

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved in .net8. I tested it out using the preview build.
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9658 was the issue with a similar stack trace.